# Change div content dynamically on other div click (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So, I'm new to AngularJS and I'm trying to change a div content after another is clicked (this one holds a div with the content that I want to put on the first one).

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="dCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="product in products">
        <li change>
            {{product.name}}
            <div class="hide">{{product.description}}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("dt", []);

app.directive("change", function() {

    return function(scope, element) {

        element.bind("click", function() {
           var message = element.children("div").text();
           console.log("breakpoint");

           angular.bind("#test", function() {
               this.text(message);
           });
        })
    }
})

app.controller("dCtrl", function($scope) {

$scope.products = [
    { "name" : "Escova XPTO", "description": "Lava tudo num instante"},
    { "name" : "Pasta de Dentes YMZ", "description": "Dentifrico do camandro"}
];

})
```

I know that I could just say:

```
$("#test").html(message);
```

But I'm still confused about mixing jQuery and AngularJS, I dont know if that is a correct way of doing it

Thanks

Comment: first of all .. your ng-repeat in on the <ul> should be on the <li> is you want several <li>s and not several <ul>

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  From your question, I can't tell, but from your HTML it looks like you're just trying to show/hide the production description when a user clicks the product name?  If so: http://jsfiddle.net/sENDS/

Comment: @Langdon = what is the .visible? The docs do not define it..or i have missed it

Comment: @BhumiSinghal it's just a variable I injected into his model.

Comment: @Langdon I'm trying to pass the {{description}} to the div #test not toggle it, can that be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Setup ng-click:**

[ngClick](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClick) is for doing things such as the scary jQuery-esque stuff you have going on in your change directive. Place ng-click in your clickable div's attributes and pass in a method that changes the $scope variable accepted by...

**[ngShow](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow) and [ngHide](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHide).**

When true these directives, as the name states, show or hide the associated html object. You can pass in $scope variables determine the boolean value. When the $scope updates these methods automatically update the DOM to show/hide the element.

Comment: I wouldn't advise using jQuery as there is certainly a better way to do it in angular.

Comment: How to do it in angular may merit another question but has likely been answered somewhere already.

Comment: I am redoing the answer hold on.

Comment: Updated. Use a mix of ngClick and ngShow/Hide write jQuery-less code.

Comment: I'm not understanding how can I pass the variables dynamically, I need the div "test" to hold a template and change its contents on each click

Comment: You "test" div has to be within the div with ng-controller for $scope to work. As long as you use the scope variables you will be able to two-way bind the data. You can still use ng-Click to change the value of your $scope.dynamicVariable.

Comment: This would work only when it is acceptable to prepopulate the #test with the product.description. What if the value needs to be send only when the div is clicked?

Comment: @BhumiSinghal you have to create a method inside your controller and bind it to ng-click. Inside it you can create scope variables and pass in params that change that variables