# how to refresh or reload a particular div on some function using angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<div id="divId_graph" ></div>
<div class="graph" id="graph" style="margin-top:-15px"></div>
```

controller.js:

```
$('#graph').svg({ onLoad:drawIntro});
```

The `drawIntro` is a function which calculate values.It's not calling when I recall the function with in same page by change some input values.

Comment: can you post the full codes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816367/how-can-i-use-ng-click-to-dynamically-reload-ng-repeat-data
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672267/refresh-data-on-click-outside-controller-in-angular
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043146/change-div-content-dynamically-on-other-div-click-angularjs

Comment: It's generally recommended to wrap DOM manipulation, like jQuery SVG, in a directive. You can then bind the input values as attributes of the directive then `$watch` for changes and redraw when a change is detected. Alternatively you could use an event listener and emit/broadcast the appropriate event to trigger a redraw.

Comment: well,i came to know that we can  do that by maintaining a separate page with the code where we want to reload and then call that page using ajax which passes values to that div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({

            type: "GET",

            url: "/templates/ch_div_content.html?loadPortion=graph",

            data: "partnerSelect="+$rootScope.partnerSelect,

            success: function(msg){

                if (box1) box1.remove();

                $("#divId_graph").html(msg);

            }

        });



the the ch-div-content.html is the part i want to reload and it is as  follows
<?php if ($loadPortion == 'graph'){ ?>                           

<script language="javascript">
if($( ".graph" )[1]!==undefined){
     $( ".graph" )[1].remove();
 }
</script>

 <div class="graph" id="graph" style="margin-top:25px">


</div>
```